# How to perform search for a Map in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart, search

I am having a Map list with key and values, for example :

```
map<String, dynamic> my_List = [{"name": "mike", "age": "20"}, {"name": "william", "age": "23"}].
```

I tried containsValue, but I don't want to use it.

The result I want to get is when search for "i" then I need to get the result like {"mike" and "william"} and when I search for "2" I need only the result {20 and 23}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
String search = "k";
var matchNames = my_List.where(p => p["name"].contains(search)).map(p => p["name"]);
String result = "";
foreach(var name in matchNames){
    result += name;
    if(name != matchNames.last){
        result += " and ";
    }
}
```